# Incorrectly Configured Rails model associations causing test failures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

I have worked through Michael Hartl's rails tutorial a few times and am now using it as a base to create my own application. Users are to be employees of universities and much of the data would be rendered in the views by university rather than simply by user. For this reason, I created a University model, seeded some university names in the universities table, used collection_select in the new user form to allow a user to select their university, and added a column university_id to my Users table. The associations I have configured are that the users belong to university and university has many users. (In the use case i'm imagining, a given university would have multiple users who can log in and see their individual data but also university-wide data)

The signup form seems to function as desired, allowing a user to select their university, sign up, and be saved to the model.

The issue is that the testing suite I built in the tutorial is now throwing multiple errors that I can't resolve after a few hours of fiddling. The errors resolve when I comment out 
    belongs_to :university
from models/user.rb

What am I doing wrong? Any and all feedback to get me unstuck and moving along again would be greatly appreciated.

Rails 5.0.1

Test Failures:

```
FAIL["test_password_resets", PasswordResetsTest, 1.204568000001018]
 test_password_resets#PasswordResetsTest (1.20s)
        Expected false to be truthy.
        test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:58:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsTest>'

/Users/MichaelBaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/will_paginate-3.1.5/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/link_renderer.rb:27: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated                                                                     ] 48% Time: 00:00:01,  ETA: 00:00:02
/Users/MichaelBaker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/will_paginate-3.1.5/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/link_renderer.rb:91: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
 FAIL["test_valid_signup_information_with_account_activation", UsersSignupTest, 2.8807119999983115]
 test_valid_signup_information_with_account_activation#UsersSignupTest (2.88s)
        "User.count" didn't change by 1.
        Expected: 35
          Actual: 34
        test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:25:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'

 FAIL["test_successful_edit", UsersEditTest, 3.048766000007163]
 test_successful_edit#UsersEditTest (3.05s)
        Expected true to be nil or false
        test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:31:in `block in <class:UsersEditTest>'

 FAIL["test_successful_edit_with_friendly_forwarding", UsersEditTest, 3.1065749999979744]
 test_successful_edit_with_friendly_forwarding#UsersEditTest (3.11s)
        Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>
        test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:49:in `block in <class:UsersEditTest>'

 FAIL["test_should_be_valid", UserTest, 3.363870000001043]
 test_should_be_valid#UserTest (3.36s)
        Expected false to be truthy.
        test/models/user_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:UserTest>'
```

test/models/user_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

      def setup
        @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", university_id: 1 , 
          password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
      end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

 test "name should be present" do
    @user.name = "     "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

    test "email should be present" do
    @user.email = "     "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

test "name should not be too long" do
    @user.name = "a" * 51
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

    test "email addresses should be unique" do
    duplicate_user = @user.dup
    duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase
    @user.save
    assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
  end

  test "email should not be too long" do
    @user.email = "a" * 244 + "@example.com"
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

   test "email validation should reject invalid addresses" do
    invalid_addresses = %w[user@example,com user_at_foo.org user.name@example.
                           foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com foo@bar..com]
    invalid_addresses.each do |invalid_address|
      @user.email = invalid_address
      assert_not @user.valid?, "#{invalid_address.inspect} should be invalid"
    end
  end
  test "password should be present (nonblank)" do
    @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " * 6
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "password should have a minimum length" do
    @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "authenticated? should return false for a user with nil digest" do
    assert_not @user.authenticated?(:remember, '')
  end
end
```

test/integration/users_edit_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersEditTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "unsuccessful edit" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_template 'users/edit'
    patch user_path(@user), params: { user: { name:  "",
                                              email: "foo@invalid",
                                              password:              "foo",
                                              password_confirmation: "bar" } }

    assert_template 'users/edit'
  end

 test "successful edit" do
  log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_template 'users/edit'
    name  = "Foo Bar"
    email = "foo@bar.com"
    patch user_path(@user), params: { user: { name:  name,
                                              email: email,
                                              password:              "",
                                              password_confirmation: "" } }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    @user.reload
    assert_equal name,  @user.name
    assert_equal email, @user.email
  end

  test "successful edit with friendly forwarding" do
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    log_in_as(@user)
    assert_redirected_to edit_user_url(@user)
    name  = "Foo Bar"
    email = "foo@bar.com"
    patch user_path(@user), params: { user: { name:  name,
                                              email: email,
                                              password:              "",
                                              password_confirmation: "" } }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    @user.reload
    assert_equal name,  @user.name
    assert_equal email, @user.email
  end
end
```

test/integration/users_signup_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
  end

  test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post users_path, params: { user: { name:  "",
                                         email: "user@invalid",
                                         university_id: 1 ,
                                         password:              "foo",
                                         password_confirmation: "bar" } }
    end
    assert_template 'users/new'
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    assert_select 'div.field_with_errors'
  end

  test "valid signup information with account activation" do
    get signup_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post users_path, params: { user: { name:  "Example User",
                                         email: "user@example.com",
                                         university_id: 1 ,
                                         password:              "password",
                                         password_confirmation: "password" } }
    end
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    user = assigns(:user)
    assert_not user.activated?
    # Try to log in before activation.
    log_in_as(user)
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    # Invalid activation token
    get edit_account_activation_path("invalid token", email: user.email)
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    # Valid token, wrong email
    get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: 'wrong')
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    # Valid activation token
    get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: user.email)
    assert user.reload.activated?
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert is_logged_in?
  end
end
```

models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :referral_requests
  belongs_to :university
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :university_id, presence: true
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true


  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
        return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end


  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

    # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  # Activates an account.
  def activate
    update_attribute(:activated,    true)
    update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end

 # Sets the password reset attributes.
  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest,  User.digest(reset_token))
    update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end

   # Returns true if a password reset has expired.
  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  end

 def feed
    ReferralRequest.where("user_id = ?", id)
  end


 private

    # Converts email to all lower-case.
    def downcase_email
    self.email = email.downcase
    end

    # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
    def create_activation_digest
      self.activation_token  = User.new_token
      self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
    end
end
```

models/university.rb

```
class University < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users
end
```

users/new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :university%>
      <%= collection_select( :user, :university_id, University.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:show, :index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

   def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @referral_requests = @user.referral_requests.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

def destroy
  User.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "User deleted"
  redirect_to users_url
end

    private

        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :university_id, :password, :password_confirmation)

  end

    # Before filters


    # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

controllers/universities_controller.rb

```
class UniversitiesController < ApplicationController
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170622190254) do

  create_table "referral_requests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.string   "preferred_gender"
    t.string   "insurance"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.index ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_referral_requests_on_user_id_and_created_at"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_referral_requests_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "universities", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
    t.boolean  "admin",             default: false
    t.string   "activation_digest"
    t.boolean  "activated",         default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string   "reset_digest"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.integer  "university_id"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end

end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post 'universities/create'

  get 'password_resets/new'

  get 'password_resets/edit'

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get  '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get  '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get  '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :referral_requests, only: [:index, :new, :create, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to modify new_framework_defaults.rb in config/initializers and change the following statement from true to false:

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
```